# Duplicate Logging Output with Root Logger

Tags: python, logging

```
import logging

# Create a logger
logger = logging.getLogger("lxy_logger")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.addHandler(console_handler)

# Log messages
logger.debug('This is a debug message')
logging.warning('This is a warning message') 
logger.error('This is another debug message')
```

the output is

```
This is a debug message
WARNING:root:This is a warning message
This is another debug message
ERROR:lxy_logger:This is another debug message
```

My question is why "This is another debug message" appeared 2 times in different forms when I ran `logger.error('This is another debug message')` after the root logger printed a warning message? At the beginning it only printed 'This is a debug message' one time when I ran `logger.debug('This is a debug message')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add handler

```
logger.addHandler(console_handler)
```

Root logger has no handlers and `lxy_logger` logger has one

```
logger.debug('This is a debug message')
```

This expectedly outputs a log message `This is a debug message`, but after you do

```
logging.warning('This is a warning message')
```

Note, that you are using `logging`, not `logger`, you actually call root logger to log a message. But it doesn't have a handler so it creates one, and outputs log message for `root` logger `WARNING:root:This is a warning message`, then

```
logger.error('This is another debug message')
```

You expect it to output log message only for `lxy_logger`, but loggers [propagate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate) their messages to higher level loggers (up to `root` logger), and now `root` logger has a handler, so it duplicates your log message

```
This is another debug message  # lxy_logger outputs
ERROR:lxy_logger:This is another debug message  # root logger gets message and outputs it again
```

Replace `logging` with `logger` and you should be good